# Stopping MySQL database server mysqld

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install postgres in my windows subsystem linux(ubuntu 20). and when I am running the following command,
`sudo apt install libpq-dev`

it is showing the following errors.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpq-dev is already the newest version (12.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                         [ OK ]
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

where is the problem and how can I overcome from this.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you tried installing MySQL but maybe aborted the install at an inopportune time. Now apt is trying to fix the install but failing.  Assuming you don't want MySQL installed, try doing `apt purge mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server`

Comment: @BrianTurek thank you for your replay.
should I completely remove MySQL ?

Comment: You definitely can have it installed but the current installation is corrupted.  If you don't have any data in MySQL to lose, I would definitely try the purge and then feel free to reinstall it.

Comment: is there any secure process to install MySql

Comment: Just doing a `apt install mysql-server` is perfectly fine.

Comment: actually i am following this tutorials to install rails on my wsl. and I am facing problem on this section.
```sudo apt install libpq-dev```

https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#postgresql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112865/discussion-between-smehsan-and-brian-turek).